# I'm trying to create a Mondrian with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I've got an assignment for Uni on creating Mondrian with the aim of the project to *Write code to generate 100 randomly sized rectangles at random locations within a canvas.*

I've attempted it and it looks like this (HTML)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Mondrian</title>
<script src="Mondrian.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Canvas style.css">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=400 height=400>
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
window.addEventListener( 'load', drawMondrian);
function drawMondrian ()
{
var canvas = document.getElementById ('myCanvas' );
var context = canvas.getContext ('2d' );
var randomSize = Math.random() * 200;
var randomXposition = Math.random() * 500;
var randomYposition = Math.random() * 500;
var shape = 1;

for (var i = shape; i < 100; i +=1)
{
context.fillRect (randomXposition, randomYposition, randomSize, randomSize);
}
}
```

I need assistance on how to get the rectangles to form all at once because so far the rectangles only appear one at a time, everytime I run or refresh the page.

Comment: Poor old Mondrian - he was a theosophist, not a random mathematician :(

Comment: @westan25 what are you doing with these edits ? It doesn't improve at all your question.

Comment: I need to hide it somehow since my semester hasn't ended yet and others can copy the code so easily

Comment: I think you should [contact SO team](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) in this case, or flag for moderation attention stating your case, but don't just deface your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your position and size declaration inside the loop. In your code you are declaring the size and position only once, then redrawing that 100 times.

```js
    window.addEventListener( 'load', drawMondrian);
    function drawMondrian ()
    {
      var canvas = document.getElementById ('myCanvas' );
      var context = canvas.getContext ('2d' );
      var shape = 1;
      var randomSize, randomXPosition, randomYposition;
    
      for (;shape < 100; shape += 1)
      {
        randomSize = Math.random() * 200;
        randomXposition = Math.random() * 500;
        randomYposition = Math.random() * 500;
        context.fillRect (randomXposition, randomYposition, randomSize, randomSize);
      }
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=400 height=400>
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag</canvas>
```

Comment: Random side note: that doesn't really look like a Mondrian though http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/zoJPxK

Comment: @Roberrrt, maybe you need [some colors](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENebVZ) (which were not picked randomly by Mondrian)

Comment: any reason why it's still not producing 100 squares? :(
Oh, also, how do I make the rectangles not have any filling in them, just the lines? isn't it just the nofill code or coding it to be white? whenever I do so, the rectangles merge into one.

Comment: @westan25 yes there was a syntax error, the iterator had `shape += shape` it was exponential so only did a couple of squares.

Comment: Thank you! How do I get rid of the filling of the rectangles? 
I seem to be stressing out on one piece of coding that I'm missing or doing some small thing wrong

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors